# Como posso criar um elemento html com classe no javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Queria fazer um alert() personalizado, e decidi tentar fazer com classe já que estou aprendendo sobre isso em alguns cursos, mas não tenho ideia de como criar um elemento html a partir da classe.

```
class Alert {
  constructor(width, height) {
      this.height = height;
      this.largura = width;
  }
  styleBox(display, bg) {
      this.style.display = display,
      this.style.backgroundColor = bg 
  }
  setContent(content) {
      this.innerHTML = '<p>'+content+'</p>'
  }
}
```

Como faço para falar que o Alert() é uma div? Geralmente, passa-se apenas atributos, que é o que fiz. Não sei se crio elemento dentro da própria classe ou fora...

Comment: São três as maneiras: [Usando elementos customizados](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), [Usando shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) e [Usando templates e slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots)

Comment: Valeu, Augusto! Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem 3 maneiras de criar Elementos no `JavaScript` no momento: Via `createElement`, via `Template Slots` e via `Web Components API`. Uma vez que a web components é pra uso mais especifico e avançado, vc pode utilizar a [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Você não precisa estar em uma classe ou ser uma classe para ter um elemento criado. Mas se vc quiser pode usar uma classe de interface par ao elemento é claro. Exemplo hipotético de classe que constrói um elemento `div` que pode conter propriedades:

```
class Alert {
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
  }

  getElement() {
    return this.div;    
  }
}
```

A classe acima cria um elemento `div` que tem um `getter` que permite que você o manipule. Você pode usar assim:

```
const alert = new Alert();

alert.getElement(); // retorna <div></div>
```

Você também pode usar o
`createElement` para passar parametros para a `div` de forma que ela contenha id, classe, estilos e o que mais vc precisar.

Note que no exemplo acima, sua `div` ainda não foi inserida no `DOM`, por isso ela ainda não existe VISUALMENTE falando. Você pode inserir no `DOM` usando o `constructor` pra isso (bad practice uma vez que fica implícito) ou pode criar um metodo para inserir de forma explícita:

```
class Alert {
  constructor() {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
  }

  getElement() {
    return this.div;    
  }

  appendTo(target) {
    if (target) {
      target.append(this.div);
    }
  }
}
```

O método `appendTo` recebe um outro elemento onde você quer que sua `div` recém criada seja adicionada. Você pode utilizá-lo para colocar a `div` na `body` do documento da seguinte maneira agora:

```
const alert = new Alert();

alert.appendTo(document.body); // adiciona <div></div> a body
```

Para criar um elemento complexo com `width` e conteúdo, você pode evoluir os parâmetros do construtor:

```
class Alert {
  constructor(width, height, textContent) {
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = textContent;

    this.div.append(p);
    this.div.style.width = width;
    this.div.style.height = height;
  }

  getElement() {
    return this.div;    
  }

  append(target) {
    if (target) {
      target.append(this.div);
    }
  }
}
```

Você também pode passar qualquer parâmetro para um elemento recém criado utilizando `Object.assign`:

```
const div = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
  id: 'div-id',
  classList: [ 'div-class-1', 'div-class-2'],
  innerHTML: '<p>Conteudo da div</p>
});
```

Enfim, isso é apenas um review e uma demonstração de algumas maneiras afim de te fornecer um start pra questão. Agora só evoluir sua classe como você quiser.

Comment: Valeu, felipe!!! Isso esclareceu bastante coisa :)